# Rabin's proofs of emptiness and complementation problems for automata on infinite trees

Tags: lo.logic, automata-theory, decidability, binary-tree

I have originally asked this question on [Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2101411/proofs-of-emptiness-and-complementation-problems-for-automata-on-infinite-trees), but I think it is more suitable here.

---

I have been reading M. Rabin's 1969 article [Decidability of Second-Order Theories and Automata on Infinite Trees](http://www.jstor.org/stable/1995086) that proves the fact that *S2S* is decidable.

**Edit.** Let me elaborate a bit on the theory behind this, as suggested by Joel David Hamkins in the comments; *S2S* here denotes the monadic second-order theory of two successors, which is modelled by the full binary tree $T_2=\{0,1\}^*$. The automata Rabin uses in his article are so called **infinite tree automata** with Büchi acceptance conditions, which are (non-deterministic) automata that accept / reject $\Sigma$-valued infinite binary trees for an alphabet $\Sigma$ (eg. as is described on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_tree_automaton)).

The proof that *S2S* is decidable relies on proofs of

> **Complementation problem** (Theorem 1.5)
>
> Given an infinite tree automaton $\mathfrak A$, if $T(\mathfrak A)$ is f.a. definable, then so is its complement.

and

> **Emptiness problem** (Theorem 1.6)
>
> For a given infinite tree automaton $\mathfrak A$, it is decidable if $T(\mathfrak A)=\emptyset$.

Contrary to automata on words and automata on finite trees, these two problems are not trivially decidable on *infinite* tree automata. Now Rabin proves the above two theorems in his paper, but as I have read in various more recent articles, the proofs Rabin gives are way too difficult. I have however not been able to find articles that actually give simpler proofs of the above theorems (apart from Rabin's 1972 *Automata on infinite objects and Church's Problem*, but the proof of the emptiness problem is still very tedious).

Now my question is, what is regarded as a good proof of the above two problems, or at least, is there an article that the authors of newer articles have in mind when saying things like "Rabin's proof is rather elaborate, but simpler proofs have subsequently been found."

Comment: Isn't the emptiness problem trivially decidable? Given an automaton, you just have to determine if you can reach an accepting state from the initial state. If so, there will be a word that is accepted. If not, then the language will be empty. Reachability in a finite digraph is decidable, since you just close the initial state under adjacency. Perhaps I've misunderstood your question?

Comment: As is remarked in Rabin's article, or maybe some other article on this subject, this is not the case for (monadic) second-order logic on infinite trees. So, this question is not about finite words and standard DFA's, but rather about automata that can accept/reject valued infinite trees (eg. $T_2 = \{0,1\}^*$ with a map $v:T_2\to\Sigma$ that assigns a letter in some alphabet $\Sigma$ to every node)

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins To clarify a bit more, acceptance conditions on these so called Büchi automata are phrased in terms of states that are visited infinitely often on an (infinite) path $\pi$ in $T_2$, considered for all paths, hence the decision method you mentioned can not be reduced to the finite case.

Comment: I would suggest, then, that you edit your question with fuller explanation about exactly what you are asking. For example, you don't mention  Büchi automata in the question, but only finite-state automata.

Comment: But incidentally, the emptiness problem for  Büchi automata is also trivially decidable: just see if you can reach an accepting state from the initial state, such that you can again reach that accepting state from that state. This can be checked by reachability methods, and it is equivalent to non-emptiness. But I guess you require the input to be a path in a certain specified tree?

Comment: This doesn't work, at least the way I see it, since the exact acceptance condition on Büchi automata *on trees* says that *for each* path $\pi$,  $In(r(\pi))$, the set of all states that are infinitely often visited, should be in a set $F$ of accepting subsets of states. This seems to be a critical difference, and I'm quite certain both of the above problems are not trivially decidable. I have edited in some details into the question as you suggested, my main idea was to target people already familiar with S2S and automata on infinite trees, but I agree my phrasing should have been more clear

Comment: My general recommendation is that MO questions should provide a full context, since the audience here is extremely diverse. For example, I am expert in Büchi automata (whose emptiness problem is indeed trivially decidable by the argument I gave), but I haven't done much with Büchi automata on trees in the style of your question, which I understand only now after this back-and-forth.

Answer (score 1):

A modern perspective on Rabin's decidability theorem for S2S uses *parity automata* over infinite binary trees. These are nondeterministic top-down automata with a "parity ranking function" $\{\text{states}\} \to \mathbb{N}$; this function is involved in defining acceptance. (What you refer to as "exact acceptance condition on Büchi automata on trees" in the comments is in fact called the *Muller condition* in the literature; Rabin's original paper used yet another acceptance condition.)

For an introduction to parity automata, you may look for instance at [Bojańczyk and Czerwiński's "Automata Toolbox" lecture notes](https://www.mimuw.edu.pl/%7Ebojan/papers/toolbox.pdf). Its section 5.3 proves complementation (Lemma 5.6) and deduces from it the equivalence between definability in Monadic Second-Order logic and parity automata (Theorem 5.5). As for emptiness, it is reducible to solving *parity games*, which are treated in Chapters 2 and 3 of the Automata Toolbox.

Addendum: if you consider logical criteria of "simplicity", as in "what are the minimal axioms required to prove Rabin's theorem", that question has been studied in the framework of reverse mathematics by [Kołodziejczyk and Michalewski](https://arxiv.org/abs/1508.06780).